# Google Analytics - profile filter to exclude group of subdomains

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

We would like to exclude a list of test/demo sub-subdomains from our profiles. For example, the subdomain.domain.com profile is showing traffic from the following sub-subdomains: test.subdomain.domain.com, demo1.subdomain.domain.com and demo2.subdomain.domain.com. show a huge amount of traffic from testing and excluding IP addresses is not feasible with many staff in many locations always changing.

We have a different profile set up for each subdomain with the following include filter added to each `subdomain\.domain\.com` so we can control which profile each department has access to with only their subdomain traffic showing in reports.

Will the following work as an 'Exclude' filter on each subdomain profile:
Filter Field: Hostname
Filter Pattern: `.*\.subdomain\.domain\.com`

If this method isn't right, it would be greatly appreciated if you could share an appropriate method.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

`.*\.subdomain\.domain\.com` worked a treat. If anyone is also interested in testing their regex / filters, [Here's a good post on quora](http://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-way-to-test-Google-Analytics-filters)